# Enter focus on a button while still being able to type in a textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there a way to have both a textbox and a button in focus? I know that I can use `textbox1.focus` to focus the textbox, and same with the button, but is there a way to be able to have enter focus on the button, while still typing in the textbox?

I know that I can just use the key-press event to capture the enter key, but I'm wondering if I can have enter focus on the button.

Just curious to know if this is possible, a simple yes or no is all that's needed. Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What is your primary issue?

Comment: Well... a **default** button works exactly this way. You don't need to have focus on both controls (also, it is not possible). The **default** button in a window or dialog will receive *enter focus* if the currently focused child control does not handle the ENTER key.

Comment: WPF or Windows Form? If WPF check for [InputBindings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputbinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @LeandroTaset Winforms, sorry for not specifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have focus on both controls to get the behavior *(I assume)* you want. Just set the parent form's or dialog's `AcceptButton` property to the button you are talking about; its `Click` event should be triggered when you press the ENTER key even while the `TextBox` has focus.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton.aspx

#### To make the answer complete *(edit)*:

As stated above in my comment to your question (and likewise by other contributors): only one control can have focus at any given time. So, the answer to your original question is:
**No, there is no way.**

Comment: Thanks, just what I wanted! Though BradleyDotNET's answer does answer the main question.

Answer (score 4):

Only one element can have input focus at a time. You can't specify the focus for just one key.

So basically, no, you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

As Bradley said, you can't.
But for your aim, there is a shortcut,  called Form.keypreview property, which let's you evaluate keys before they reach the textbox or other controls.